# Updating observable collection from background thread + WPF + silent update

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I am planning to have a threadsafe observable collection, where in I run a task on the background and update the UI as and when result is obtained using the dispatcher.

I got a download from the internet which is ThreadSafe. But I have a small concern. I wish to do a silent update on the UI. Since the user is already working or selecting the bound collection, I would not want to disturb the user selected entry. In other words, I would like to add an entry similar to Microsoft Outlook, when a new mail arrives.

Is this possible, and are there any such examples.

Thanks

Comment: You approach is flawed... if your `ObservableCollection` is data bound to a UI control, then you will get the famous *You cannot update a UI property from a different thread* error. Typically, we just fetch and prepare our data in a background thread and then update the UI collection property on the UI thread.

Comment: @Sheridan the problem is I cannot wait till I generate all the data and block the UI.. I want the user to work on the list at the same time, it gets updated with new entry (every now and then) in the end, without disturbing the user selection.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand my comment? We *don't* wait or block UI threads while we are fetching or preparing our data in a background thread. By all means, continue on this path and I look forward to seeing your next related questions here.

Comment: @Sheridan please give me some time, I shall do some more coding and upload a piece of sample code, meanwhile, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can have derived class from ObservableCollection and override it OnCollectionChanged function and raise it handler when ever you require. follows are code.

```
 public class ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
 {
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    private bool suspendCollectionChangeNotification;

  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

                if (!this.suspendCollectionChangeNotification)
                {
                    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler eventHandler = CollectionChanged;
                    if (eventHandler != null)
                    {
                        Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

                        // Walk through invocation list
                        bool isEventInvoked = false;
                        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in delegates)
                        {
                            isEventInvoked = false;
                            if (handler.Target is DispatcherObject)
                            {
                                DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

                                // This check is to make sure if the call on a different thread than the dispatcher.
                                if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.CheckAccess() == false)
                                {
                                    // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread
                                    // Intentionally called begin invoke because there is a problem with Dispatcher.Invoke that it hangs when
                                    // called simultaneously
                                    dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
                                    isEventInvoked = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!isEventInvoked)
                            {
                                handler(this, e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

}
```